# tight_layout() doesn't take into account figure suptitle

Tags: python, matplotlib, suptitle

If I add a subtitle to my matplotlib figure it gets overlaid by the subplot's titles. Does anybody know how to easily take care of that? I tried the `tight_layout()` function, but it only makes things worse.

Example:

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = np.random.random(100)
g = np.random.random(100)
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Long Suptitle', fontsize=24)
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(f)
plt.title('Very Long Title 1', fontsize=20)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(g)
plt.title('Very Long Title 2', fontsize=20)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 300, accepted):

You can adjust the subplot geometry in the very `tight_layout` call as follows:

```
fig.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.03, 1, 0.95])
```

As it's stated in the documentation (https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html):

> `tight_layout()` only considers ticklabels, axis labels, and titles. Thus, other artists may be clipped and also may overlap.

Comment: It worked like charm, but how the change happens when specifying bounding box? I read the doc but not much was clear to me. It would be great if you could please explain to me! Thanks.

Comment: could you please explain the meaning of each number in rect? I didn't see them in the doc.

Comment: @steven see `tight_layout` docs: `[left, bottom, right, top] in normalized (0, 1) figure coordinates`

Comment: You can increase the space between suptitle and axes even more by lowering the rightest value: `tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.03, 1, 0.9])` instead of `0.95` as in the answer.

Comment: Did not work inside jupyter. Tried different values for numbers, had no effect

Comment: This does not seem to have an effect.

Comment: You, sir, are the MVP!

Answer (score 140):

You could manually adjust the spacing using `plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = np.random.random(100)
g = np.random.random(100)
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Long Suptitle', fontsize=24)
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(f)
plt.title('Very Long Title 1', fontsize=20)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(g)
plt.title('Very Long Title 2', fontsize=20)
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Note the default value for top is 0.9 when you call `subplots_adjust`

Comment: Note that `subplots_adjust` must be called *after* any calls to `tight_layout`, or there will be no effect of calling `subplots_adjust`.

Comment: @wordsforthewise make that 2018 now

Comment: Bug or not bug, placing a title should be simpler.

Answer (score 67):

One thing you could change in your code very easily is the `fontsize` you are using for the titles. However, I am going to assume that you don't just want to do that!

Some alternatives to using `fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)`:

Usually `tight_layout()` does a pretty good job at positioning everything in good locations so that they don't overlap. The reason `tight_layout()` doesn't help in this case is because **`tight_layout()` does not take fig.suptitle() into account.** There is an open issue about this on GitHub: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/829 [closed in 2014 due to requiring a full geometry manager - shifted to https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1109 ].

If you read the thread, there is a solution to your problem involving `GridSpec`. The key is to leave some space at the top of the figure when calling `tight_layout`, using the `rect` kwarg. For your problem, the code becomes:

**Using GridSpec**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

f = np.random.random(100)
g = np.random.random(100)

fig = plt.figure(1)
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)
ax_list = [fig.add_subplot(ss) for ss in gs1]

ax_list[0].plot(f)
ax_list[0].set_title('Very Long Title 1', fontsize=20)

ax_list[1].plot(g)
ax_list[1].set_title('Very Long Title 2', fontsize=20)

fig.suptitle('Long Suptitle', fontsize=24)    

gs1.tight_layout(fig, rect=[0, 0.03, 1, 0.95])  

plt.show()
```

The result:

[image: using gridspec]

Maybe `GridSpec` is a bit overkill for you, or your real problem will involve many more subplots on a much larger canvas, or other complications. A simple hack is to just use `annotate()` and lock the coordinates to the `'figure fraction'` to imitate a `suptitle`. You may need to make some finer adjustments once you take a look at the output, though. Note that this second solution does **not** use `tight_layout()`.

**Simpler solution** (though may need to be fine-tuned)

```
fig = plt.figure(2)

ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax1.plot(f)
ax1.set_title('Very Long Title 1', fontsize=20)

ax2 = plt.subplot(122)
ax2.plot(g)
ax2.set_title('Very Long Title 2', fontsize=20)

# fig.suptitle('Long Suptitle', fontsize=24)
# Instead, do a hack by annotating the first axes with the desired 
# string and set the positioning to 'figure fraction'.
fig.get_axes()[0].annotate('Long Suptitle', (0.5, 0.95), 
                            xycoords='figure fraction', ha='center', 
                            fontsize=24
                            )
plt.show()
```

The result:

[image: simple]

[Using `Python` 2.7.3 (64-bit) and `matplotlib` 1.2.0]

Comment: Thanks, if I use the first solution you suggested (using `GridSpec`) how can I create subplots that share axes? I usually use `plt.subplots(N,1, sharex=<>, sharey=<>)` when creating subplots, but the code you posted uses `add_subplot` instead

Comment: Casting `fig.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.03, 1, 0.95])` also works.

Answer (score 28):

Tight layout doesn't work with suptitle, but `constrained_layout` does. See this question [Improve subplot size/spacing with many subplots in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541123/improve-subplot-size-spacing-with-many-subplots-in-matplotlib)

I found adding the subplots at once looked better, i.e.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(rows, cols, constrained_layout=True)

# then iterating over the axes to fill in the plots
```

But it can also be added at the point the figure is created:

```
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(cols, rows, 1)
# etc
```

Note: To make my subplots closer together, I was also using

```
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05)
```

and constrained_layout doesn't work with this :(

Answer (score 23):

An alternative and simple to use solution is to adjust the coordinates of the suptitle text in the figure using the y argument in the call of suptitle (see the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html?highlight=suptitle#matplotlib.figure.Figure.suptitle)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = np.random.random(100)
g = np.random.random(100)
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Long Suptitle', y=1.05, fontsize=24)
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(f)
plt.title('Very Long Title 1', fontsize=20)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(g)
plt.title('Very Long Title 2', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is a great way in a notebook but the plt.savefig() command does not obey. This solution still cuts off the title in a savefig command.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by others, by default the tight layout does not take suptitle into account. However, I have found it is possible to use the `bbox_extra_artists` argument to pass in the suptitle as a bounding box that should be taken into account:

```
st = fig.suptitle("My Super Title")
plt.savefig("figure.png", bbox_extra_artists=[st], bbox_inches='tight')
```

This forces the tight layout calculation to take the `suptitle` into account, and it looks as you would expect.

Comment: This is the only option that worked for me. I use Jupyter notebooks to make figures and save them. I work in python 3.6 on a Linux machine.

Comment: This, alas, resulted in far too much space in my case between the title and the first (top) subplot.

Comment: @BrandonRhodes I can't confirm that this will work for you, but in my case, using the `constrained_layout=True` optional argument in the `plt.subplots` call *in addition to* `bbox_extra_artists` in `plt.savefig` eliminated the excess space.

Comment: `constrained_layout=True` did the trick!

Answer (score 6):

[This website](https://gist.github.com/donkirkby/36e8c208926e2e85ca9dbd975fc9599f) has a simple solution to this with an example that worked for me. The line of code that does the actual leaving of space for the title is the following:

```
plt.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, 1, 0.95])
```

Here is an image of proof that it worked for me:
[image: Image Link]

Answer (score 6):

As of [v3.3](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/users/whats_new.html#tight-layout-now-supports-suptitle) `tight_layout` now supports `suptitle`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3)
for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
    ax.plot([1, 2, 3])
    ax.set_title(f'Axes {i}')

fig.suptitle('suptitle')
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have struggled with the matplotlib trimming methods, so I've now just made a function to do this via a `bash` call to `ImageMagick`'s [mogrify command](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php), which works well and gets all extra white space off the figure's edge. This requires that you are using UNIX/Linux, are using the `bash` shell, and have `ImageMagick` installed.

Just throw a call to this after your `savefig()` call.

```
def autocrop_img(filename):
    '''Call ImageMagick mogrify from bash to autocrop image'''
    import subprocess
    import os

    cwd, img_name = os.path.split(filename)

    bashcmd = 'mogrify -trim %s' % img_name
    process = subprocess.Popen(bashcmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=cwd)
```

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that worked for me was modifying the call to suptitle:

```
fig.suptitle("title", y=.995)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue that cropped up when using `tight_layout` for a very large grid of plots (more than 200 subplots) and rendering in a jupyter notebook.  I made a quick solution that always places your `suptitle` at a certain distance above your top subplot:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_rows = 50
n_col = 4
fig, axs = plt.subplots(n_rows, n_cols)

#make plots ...

# define y position of suptitle to be ~20% of a row above the top row
y_title_pos = axs[0][0].get_position().get_points()[1][1]+(1/n_rows)*0.2
fig.suptitle('My Sup Title', y=y_title_pos)
```

For variably-sized subplots, you can still use this method to get the top of the topmost subplot, then manually define an additional amount to add to the suptitle.