# GridSpec with shared axes in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19627237/283296) to another thread suggests using `gridspec.GridSpec` instead of `plt.subplots`. However, when I share axes between subplots, I usually use a syntax like the following

```
  fig, axes = plt.subplots(N, 1, sharex='col', sharey=True, figsize=(3,18))
```

How can I specify `sharex` and `sharey` when I use `GridSpec` ?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

First off, there's an easier workaround for your original problem, as long as you're okay with being slightly imprecise. Just reset the top extent of the subplots to the default *after* calling `tight_layout`:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)
plt.setp(axes, title='Test')
fig.suptitle('An overall title', size=20)

fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9) 

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

However, to answer your question, you'll need to create the subplots at a slightly lower level to use gridspec.  If you want to replicate the hiding of shared axes like `subplots` does, you'll need to do that manually, by using the `sharey` argument to [`Figure.add_subplot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot) and hiding the duplicated ticks with `plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)`.

As an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,2)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1], sharey=ax1)
plt.setp(ax2.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)

plt.setp([ax1, ax2], title='Test')
fig.suptitle('An overall title', size=20)
gs.tight_layout(fig, rect=[0, 0, 1, 0.97])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `plt.setp(ax2.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)` is not necessary for removing the y-axis labels

Comment: Once you have the gridspec you can create all the subplots at once with sharex and sharey: `axs = my_gridspec.subplots(sharex='row', sharey='col')`

Comment: I like the first example. To get rid of the space, add `, gridspec_kw = {'wspace': 0}`. Keep `sharey=True` to ensure same scaling.

Answer (score 26):

Both Joe's choices gave me some problems: the former, related with direct use of `figure.tight_layout` instead of `figure.set_tight_layout()` and, the latter, with some backends (*UserWarning: tight_layout : falling back to Agg renderer*). But Joe's answer definitely cleared my way toward another compact alternative. This is the result for a problem close to the OP's one:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex='col', sharey=True,
                               gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [2, 1]},
                               figsize=(4, 7))
fig.set_tight_layout({'rect': [0, 0, 1, 0.95], 'pad': 1.5, 'h_pad': 1.5})
plt.setp(axes, title='Test')
fig.suptitle('An overall title', size=20)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I made a function where you input a list or array of axes and it shares x or y along the rows and cols as specified. Not fully tested but here's the gist of it:

```
def share_axes(subplot_array, sharex, sharey, delete_row_ticklabels = 1, delete_col_ticklabels = 1):
    shape = np.array(subplot_array).shape
    if len(shape) == 1:
            for i, ax in enumerate(subplot_array):
                if sharex:
                    ax.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax, subplot_array[0])
                    if delete_row_ticklabels and not(i==len(subplot_array)-1):
                        ax.set_xticklabels([])
                if sharey:
                    ax.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax, subplot_array[0])
                    if delete_col_ticklabels and not(i==0):
                        ax.set_yticklabels([])
    elif len(shape) == 2:
        for i in range(shape[0]):
            for j in range(shape[1]):
                ax = subplot_array[i,j]
                if sharex in ('rows', 'both'):
                    ax.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax, subplot_array[-1,j])
                    if delete_row_ticklabels and not(i==shape[0]-1):
                        ax.set_xticklabels([])
                if sharey in ('rows', 'both'):
                    ax.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax, subplot_array[-1,j])
                if sharex in ('cols', 'both'):
                    ax.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax, subplot_array[i,0])
                if sharey in ('cols', 'both'):
                    if delete_col_ticklabels and not(j==0):
                        ax.set_yticklabels([])
                    ax.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax, subplot_array[i,0])
```