# FacetGrid axes sharing x axis across rows / y-axis across columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

[`FacetGrid`](https://stanford.edu/%7Emwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) from `seaborn` creates a grid of subpots allowing you to explore conditional relationships in your dataset.

Two of the keyword arguments the function accepts are `sharex` and `sharey`, which according to the docs:

> **share{x,y}** : bool, optional
>
> > If true, the facets will share y axes across columns and/or x axes across rows.

But I don't see any other way to control the way facets/subplots share axes. And so here comes the...

#### Question:

Is there any way to share the x axis across columns and/or the y axes across rows?

I'm trying to obtain density plots of different quantities (in rows) for different conditions (in columns and hue). Thus, I would my subplots to share both the x and y axis across rows, but no linkage across columns.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's not properly documented, but those parameters are passed straight to `plt.subplots`, which allows you to set the values for those parameters to `"row"` or `"col"` so that axes are only shared within rows or columns, and not across the whole grid.

I'm not sure I understand exactly how you want your plot to look, but I think you can do something like:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="smoker", row="time", sharey="col")
g.map(plt.hist, "total_bill")
```

That said, in general I would try to share axes across the grid (i.e., structure the plot to share y axes across the rows, not across the columns) to ease visual comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

The `FacetGrid` object contains a collection of axes (a numpy array in the shape of the grid). You could manually set axes limits on each axis in the array. That requires a lot of iteration/post-processing, though. Below is a quick example.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.random(1000), 
                     'b':np.random.random(1000), 
                     'c':np.random.random_integers(0,3,1000),
                     'x':np.random.random_integers(1,5,1000),
                     'y':np.random.random_integers(1,5,1000)})

g = sns.FacetGrid(data=data, col='x', row='y', hue='c', sharex=False, sharey=False)
g.map(plt.scatter, 'a', 'b').add_legend()
for axlist in g.axes:
    for ax in axlist:
        ax.set_ylim(.2,.3)
    break
print(type(g.axes))
plt.show()
```

However, if you don't mind skipping `seaborn` and working directly in `matplotlib`, you can work with a `GridSpec` object instead of a FacetGrid, as seen in the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511550/gridspec-with-shared-axes-in-python). Then you can specify specifically which axes are shared.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

data = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.random(1000), 
                     'b':np.random.random(1000), 
                     'c':np.random.random_integers(0,3,1000),
                     'x':np.random.random_integers(1,5,1000),
                     'y':np.random.random_integers(1,5,1000)})

colors = ['b', 'r', 'g', 'y']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(len(data['x'].unique()),len(data['y'].unique()))
g = data.groupby(['x','y'])
for i, (ind, grp) in enumerate(g):
    if i % 5 == 0: 
        ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[i])
    else:
        ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[i], sharex = ax)
        plt.setp(ax2.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)

    subgroups = grp.groupby('c')
    for index, sub in subgroups:
        plt.scatter(sub['a'], sub['b'], color=colors[index])


plt.show()
```

In this example, we share the x-axes across rows (each `i % 5 == 0`). Since the GridSpec object is just a numpy array of axes, we can initialize them in any convenient order and share axes as we wish. With `GridSpec`, you have a lot more customization, but a lot of the nice parts of `seaborn` (hue, etc) have to be coded manually.

Comment: I knew GridSpec, but I wanted to avoid getting into that when it is so easy with `FacetGrid`... Thanks anyway! :)