# avoid overlap of ylabel on a graph in a matplotlib multiaxis figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, overlap, figure

I have a matplotlib figure with some subplots, is there an easy way to avoid overlap of ylabel of an Axes on another like this ?

[image]

Comment: It's a good question, but also a frequently-asked one.  This duplicate is not a 100% match, but the root cause and solution is the same.  `tight_layout` will try to auto-adjust things to make room for the labels, or you can use `subplots_adjust` to manually accomplish the same thing.  If anyone finds a closer duplicate, feel free to reassign things.

Comment: Fine, it works. But now, the titles of my subplots are overlaping the main title of figure ...

Comment: you need to add `plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.90)` as in 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248467/matplotlib-tight-layout-doesnt-take-into-account-figure-suptitle