# How to avoid the overlapping between "suptitle" and "subplots" when using python matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a matrix to compare some data. But the title of plot is overlapping with the subplots:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sn
   
def save_graph_cm(CMatrix):
    # CMatrix is a dict with four 3x3 pandas DataFrame
    k = 'Wine'
    id = 0
    cm = 1
    plt.suptitle("#" + str(id) + " Confusion Matrix for " + k + " dataset")
    for c_matrix in CMatrix:
        plt.subplot(2, 2, cm)
        sn.heatmap(CMatrix[c_matrix], annot=True, cmap="YlOrRd")
        plt.title("CV - " + str(cm-1))
        plt.xlabel("Predicted Classes")
        plt.ylabel("Real Classes")
        cm += 1
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show
```

What I am getting now is:

[image]

Comment: Try w constrained_layout instead of tight_layout.  The former takes into account subtitles

Comment: it didn't work... what worked was using Figure and subplots_adjust()

Comment: `constrained_layout` definitely works.  But you need to make your plot compatible: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html#suptitle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib tight\_layout() doesn't take into account figure suptitle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66789231/9067615)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of [v3.3](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/users/whats_new.html#tight-layout-now-supports-suptitle), matplotlib's `tight_layout` now displays `suptitle` correctly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3)
for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
    ax.plot([1, 2, 3])
    ax.set_title(f'Axes {i}')

fig.suptitle('suptitle')
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, using GridSpec as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19627237/8079057 fixed it for me.