# How can I add an arbitrarily big white margin to a figure with subplots?

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to add an arbitrarily big white margin (or padding) to a figure with subplots because I would like the `subtitle` of the figure not to overlap with any of the subplots or titles of these subplots. I am using Matplotlib 3.1.2.

Currently, I have the following source code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(15, 10))

n = 10
x = np.arange(0, n)
y = np.random.rand(n)

ax[0].plot(x, y)
ax[0].set_xlabel('x')
ax[0].set_ylabel('y')

y = np.random.rand(n)

ax[1].plot(x, y)
ax[1].set_xlabel('x')
ax[1].set_ylabel('y')

fig.suptitle("I want to have white space around me!!!")
# fig.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.03, 1, 0.80])
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)

plt.show()
```

If I try to use either `tight_layout` or `subplots_adjust` (as suggested in several answers to this question [Matplotlib tight_layout() doesn't take into account figure suptitle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8248467/3924118)), it doesn't seem to have any effect on the margins. Here's the result of the execution of the previous example.

[image]

Is there a way to add an arbitrarily big white margin to the left, right, bottom and (or) top of a figure (with subplots)? I would like to specify the figure size and arbitrarily increase or decrease the white space around an image. I also would like the solution to work in case I decide to add a title for each of the subplots. How can this be done?

Comment: I guess you're working in a jupyter notebook? If so, the figure you would save with `fig.savefig("output.png")` would be correct, right?! And you would get the desired figure via `%config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs = {'bbox_inches':None}` in an empty cell before your code. Or you can use the `%matplotlib notebook` backend.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest No, I am not working with Jupyter notebooks. I am working with PyCharm in a virtual environment.

Comment: Ok, can you still try outside of pycharm (but still inside the virtual environment)? Would `fig.savefig("output.png")` give the correct output, or not? Does using a normal backend like `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("TkAgg")` make it work?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Outside of PyCharm, the example above adds white space around the supertitle, even without using `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("TkAgg")`. However, I have another (quite different) example, where, even if I execute it outside of PyCharm (i.e. from the terminal), it does not add the white space.

Comment: The use of the TkAgg backend was meant to see if it can change anything within PyCharm. If you want to share a [mcve] of the other quite different example, I can see why it doesn't work outside of PyCharm. (PyCharm is closed source, so it's generally hard to know why something doesn't work)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It's so annoying! Sometimes it seems to work, sometimes it doesn't. Now, I can't even plot an image, even though I am calling `show`.

Answer (score 0):

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(5,5))
fig.patch.set_facecolor('grey')
fig.suptitle("Look at all that grey space around me!!!")
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.6, bottom=0.4, left=0.4, right=0.6)
```

[image]

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what OP tried already and which fails in their case.