# How to adjust the position of suptitle and title of subplot in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I create a figure with multiple subplots. The figure has its title and each subplot has its respective title.  The figure title uses `plt.suptitle('Test',size=20)`. In the generated figure, shown as follows, the figure title and titles for the first subplot overlap with each other. How to solve this issue.

The major code for generating the related figure is as follows, and the details are comments out.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6*1, 4*6))
for i in range(6):
    plt.subplot(6,1,i+1)
    # the code for plotting the data are skipped
    plt.title('title for subplots',size=10)
plt.suptitle('Test',size=20)
```

[image]

Comment: Often, `plt.tight_layout()` helps for these situations.

Comment: @johanC, I had plt.tight_layout(), but it does not impact the result.

Comment: Well, if you used it, it really helps to show it in the code. It has quite a large influence.  You could try `plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.95)` after `plt.tight_layout()` to have more space. I am not sure why `tight_layout` doesn't work well here.  In  [Matplotlib tight_layout() doesn't take into account figure suptitle(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248467/matplotlib-tight-layout-doesnt-take-into-account-figure-suptitle) someone suggests to use constrained layout, as in `fig, axs = plt.subplots(6,1,figsize=(6*1, 4*6), constrained_layout=True)`

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle`'s `x` and `y` parameters allow you to specify the position of the title in the figure (docs [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle.html)). Try `y=1.0` to start with (leaving `x` to its default value `0.5`) and tweak as needed:

```
plt.suptitle('Test', size=20, y=1.0)
```