# How to avoid overlapping between plot titles and axis titles in histogram subplots in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, overlap

I have this plot made in pandas:

[image]

I want to have more space between the titles of the plots and the axis of the following ones, so that they dont overlap. I have tried the solutions of the question [Improve subplot size/spacing with many subplots in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541123/improve-subplot-size-spacing-with-many-subplots-in-matplotlib) but none of them makes nothing to my plot.

Comment: You need to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418125/matplotlib-subplots-adjust-hspace-so-titles-and-xlabels-dont-overlap) out

Comment: By the way, did you try using `plt.tight_layout()`

Comment: I guess I was typing it before df.hist() and thats why it did not work, but now it does. Thank you. You can answer the question so that I can vote yours as correct answer

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `plt.tight_layout()` after plotting all the figures. This avoids manually playing around with the spacing.

Comment: Doing so destroys the aspect ratio of my subplots. Previously they're squares, then after `plt.tight_layout()`, they're rectangles. Do you know how to prevent this?