# Avoid overlapping between figure title and axis titles

Tags: python, matplotlib

**EDIT**

I have finally solved the problem, turns out it was all a bug of the SciView feature in PyCharm, but saving the image as @Bazingaa suggested and adding either of the solutions, i.e. `constrained_layout` or `tight_layout` has solved it for me, so the question can be closed. 
Thanks all for the help :)

**QUESTION**

I know this question has been asked before, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541123/improve-subplot-size-spacing-with-many-subplots-in-matplotlib) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52236996/how-to-avoid-overlapping-between-plot-titles-and-axis-titles-in-histogram-subplo). However, for some reason, none of the solutions provided has worked for me so far.

I have a figure with two subplots, each of them having its own title and the figure having a title too. The problem is that the title of the figure overlaps with the titles of the axes.

Here is the sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 3))
# fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 3), constrained_layout=True)

data = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)

fig.suptitle('Comparison of distribution in different pieces')

ax[0].set_title('Original distributions')
ax[0].hist(x=data, density=True,
           edgecolor='k')

ax[1].set_title('Standardized distribution')
ax[1].hist(x=data, density=True,
           edgecolor='k')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

As you can see I am already using `plt.tight_layout()`, and I have tried increasing the top margin using `plt.adjust_subplots()`, and also setting the `constrained_layout` parameter on the figure to `True`, but I get exactly the same image no matter how I change the parameters of these functions, or even without calling either of them.

Here is the [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhiKl.png).

Also, any advice or correction regarding this code would be appreciated as I am still a newbie with matplotlib.

P.S. Thanks @Bazingaa for letting me use his code as an example for my problem.

Comment: Try using constrained layout instead of tight layout if you are on a recent enough matplotlib

Comment: @JodyKlymak Also tried that, but didn't work, the result is the exact same...

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the y-location for the main title (`suptitle`) using the `y` keyword. Below is a sample answer.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 3))  # specify figsize later

data = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)

fig.suptitle('Comparison of distribution in different pieces', y=1.05)

ax[0].set_title('Original distributions')
ax[0].hist(x=data, density=True,
           edgecolor='k')

ax[1].set_title('Standardized distribution')
ax[1].hist(x=data, density=True,
           edgecolor='k')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Bazingaa. 

I tried your solution and it does not work either, the suptitle does not appear in the figure specifying a y higher than 1.0, even in the code you provided. I think it maybe has to do with the plot visor in PyCharm, which is the IDE I am using for this task, so I'll try to figure it out outside of the IDE.

Comment: @user3897600: In that case, I would suggest you to include a complete minimal code in your question which reproduces your problem

Comment: @user3897600: What if you save the figure?

Comment: do you mind if I borrow your code as an example? It reproduces exactly my problem. 

I have also tried saving the figure and I get the same result.

Comment: @user3897600: Sure, be my guest

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the space used by `tight_layout()` for the subplots at the top with the `rect` keyword, e.g.:

```
plt.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, 0, .95])
```

Comment: Thanks man, that worked when I saved the image although in the SciView of PyCharm it still does not work. Again, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ooops, sorry, didn't read your update.

This works for me:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 3), constrained_layout=True)

data = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
fig.suptitle('Comparison of distribution in different pieces')


ax[0].set_title('Original distributions')
ax[0].hist(x=data, density=True,
           edgecolor='k')

ax[1].set_title('Standardized distribution')
ax[1].hist(x=data, density=True,
           edgecolor='k')

plt.show()
```

[image: suptitle]